# Heroku Gradle buildpack: How to enable the --info switch

Tags: gradle, heroku

My app's deployment is failing in Heroku. In order to debug what's wrong, I need to enable the --info (or --debug) and maybe --stacktrace command line parameter. I've read through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku but I failed to find any documentation on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: just set the `GRADLE_TASK="stage --info --stacktrace"` config variable as documented at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku

[image]